How do I fill missing values in a dataframe with the values found in another dataframe using a lookup value?
Basically, I have a df with car model+year as a string in 1 column. The dataframe is a collection of used cars for sale so there are duplicate model+year rows but not duplicated entire rows. In this df there are missing values for basic car information like number of seats etc. Example below
model_year: A4_2022, mustang_1966, A4_2022, defender_1988
engine: v4, v8, null, null
seats: null, 5, null, 8
In a separate df I have the full values for a collection of model+year (not all).
model_year: a4_2022, defender_1988
engine: v4, v8
seates: 5, 8
**How can I go through the first dataframe, check for missing values, where there is missing -> pull value from the second dataframe where model_year match?
**
I tried the following but it didn't seem to fill the missing values. Is the code wrong? It is also possible that the model_year in the first dataframe just doesn't exist in the second dataframe.
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(row['Seats']):
        model = row['model_year']
        seats = df_model[df_model['model_year'] == model]['Seats'].values
        if len(seats) > 0:
            df.loc[index, 'Seats'] = seats[0]


You're looking for
.merge().
Or the associated
tutorial.
(There's also a
cookbook
and
join docs].)
